# How to preprocess data for clustering weka

Tags: attributes, instance, cluster-analysis, weka, large-data

I have a large amount of attributes(~110.000) and around 80 instances,which i want to cluster.The attributes have distict values,usually 0 and 1..I would like to remove all the attributes which show up too often or almost never,like for example an attribute which value is 0/1 for 78 out of the 80 instances or for 2 out of the 80 instances..Is there any way to do that in weka?

Comment: Weka has many methods for selecting attributes. Have you tired anything such as Information Gain or Principal Component Analysis?

Comment: If I'm not wrong the Select Attributes function need a relative class to work best with..We don't have a main class based on which I can compare the attributes..

Answer (score 0):

In the "preprocess" Tab, there is a "removeUseless" Attribute-Filter.

See Filters / Unsupervised / Attribute / removeUseless. Have you tried it?

From the description:

> "This filter removes attributes that do not vary at all or that vary
>   too much."

This can be done by tuning the `maximumvariancePercentageAllowed` parameter. Default is 99%.